# Which model to use for panel probit when the outcome variable doesn't vary in a group?

Tags: panel-data, probit

In the data which I am working on, the dependent variable is binary and it doesn't vary across time for a particular group. For example, I have data of 12 years for 16 countries in which the outcome is 1 for 5 countries and 0 for the remaining 11 countries. There is no time variation in the outcome variable. How should I estimate this model? Is a panel probit with random effects suitable for it?

Comment: If the outcome is invariant over time, why would you want to include multiple time points; What is the goal here?

Comment: How else should I proceed? The data I have is in a panel format, the explanatory variables are variant over time and individuals but the outcome variable is variant only across individuals. How should this data structure be used? If I don't include multiple time points, the number of individual is very less.

Comment: Then I don't understand what you mean by "variable doesn't vary", do you mean on average over the individuals in a group?

Comment: Should I use the mean of the explanatory variables across time and run a cross sectional regression instead?

Comment: The outcome variable (binary) does not vary over time for a particular country, the explanatory variables do. So for example, there is evidence of spillovers for China, so the dependent variable is 1 for it for all the time periods.Similarly, it is 1 for 5 economies and 0 for the remaining 11 economies in my sample.